# Java Socket and ServerSocket Issue

Tags: sockets

I have this code snippet:

```
ServerSocket serversocket=new ServerSocket(DEFAULTPORT);
serversocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
Socket socket=serversocket.accept();
```

1. Does closing the `serversocket` object also affects the state of the `socket` object?
2. If I close the `serversocket` object can I still use the `socket` object for my streams?

Comment: huh? what does it has to do with my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answers are:

> 1) no
>
> 2) yes

The longer answer is:

The ServerSocket waits for clients to connect (he waits in his accept-method). When there is a client, the accept-method returns, more specifically it returns a Socket-object which then represents the server's endpoint of the server-client connection. If the server closes his server-socket, he no longer listens (he no longer accepts new clients) but the clients with which he already has a socket-connection are unaffected.

Your code is not "wrong" per se, however it is only capable of accepting a single client and only if it connected within 1000 milliseconds.

Here is an introduction including sample code:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: super thanks! the codes was just for clarification so that readers can understand what i meant.